# GWT DateBox not working properly in iframe on iOS 10.1.1

Tags: ios, iframe, gwt

When including GWT DateBox in an iframe, its not possible to switch month or year.

When trying to click the next or previous arrow, it unexpectedly scrolls down a lot.

- Happens only on iOS 10.1.1 (All Browsers: Chrome, Safari, Firefox)
- Same issue on iPhone and iPad
- Does not happen on older iOS versions.
- Does not happen without iframe.

Here a minimal Example to reproduce the issue:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <iframe src="http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDatePicker" height="5800px" width="100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Any hint?

Comment: Your example isn't showing due to same-origin-policy...

Comment: Ah I can see, the snippet can't be run here. It needs to be copied to a file. I still did not found the cause why this is happening...